# How to resize csh/bash console after exiting vim with either ":wq!" or "q!"

Tags: bash, vim, window, size, csh

I have my vim setup so that it changes the columns and lines when entering vim. Is there a way to automatically restore console size after leaving vim?

This is all I have in my .vimrc:

```
set lines=45 columns=90
```

When I enter dimensions are good, but when I leave the console stays at that height and weight too. I'd like it to go back to the console height after leaving vim editor with either ":wq!" o ":q!"

Comment: Show us your setup so we can tell you how to revert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save values of "columns" and "lines" options in variables before setting them. And then restore them by autocommand VimLeave.

this example works fine on my vim:

```
let old_lines=&lines    
let old_columns=&columns    
set lines=45 columns=90    

au VimLeave * : let &lines=old_lines    
au VimLeave * : let &columns=old_columns
```